# setting double quotes around lowercase oracle database names

Tags: database, oracle, lowercase

we have oracle databases with names and columns in lowercase and we need a way to handle this problem, because without double quotes around the lowercase identifiers, Informatica PowerCenter doesn't find those tables.  Is there an option in oracle that sets every identifier in double quotes automatically before executing a query?

Comment: You have run into a BIG problem. The ideal fix is to rebuild your database with object names that are not case sensitive. But I doubt that will be feasible. For now you probably need to create synonyms and views to get around your design issue

Comment: thank you, synonym helps to handle this for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an option in oracle that sets every identifier in double quotes automatically before executing a query?

No, you either need to use:

- double quotes around every identifier;
- rename the tables and columns so they aren't defined using lower-case characters; or
- create views of your tables that have upper-case identifiers for the table name and columns so that Oracle's default behaviour (of converting every unquoted identifier to upper-case) can be used.